# Why isn't the user being saved in the installation class?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to save the users token in the installation class but nothing is being added to the class.

This is the chunk of code in my app delegate to register the token and create a row for that user.

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current Installation and save it to Parse
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    if let username = PFUser.currentUser()?.username {
installation.setObject(username, forKey: "user")
}
    installation.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            print("saved installation")
        }else{
            print(error)
        }
    })


}
```

I placed the below chunk in my profile view which is the view controller presented after logging in. I moved it from the app delegate because I wanted the user to be prompted to allow notifications after they logged in. The problem is that the `didRegisterForRemoteNotifications...` is not being called.

```
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Sound, .Badge], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind is: are you running this in the Simulator? If yes, you won't be able to get a device token anyhow, because the Simulator does not handle remote notifications.

Secondly, this line:

```
installation["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
```

**Should actually be:**

```
if let user = PFUser.currentUser()? {
    installation.setObject(user, forKey: "user")
}
```

Parse's iOS library hasn't been ported to Swift so it doesn't handle subscription at the moment.

Comment: I am using an actual device, but it still does not work. I get this error http://puu.sh/m0pLw/aa56739b58.png

Comment: I edited the answer to accommodate this error. Would you mind trying again?